# Problem using Loop Cut and Slide

Tags: mesh

I'm following a tutorial for beginners and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong despite a lot of time trying to figure it out.

When using the Loop Cut and Slide tool it is behaving differently for me than it does in the video I'm following.  I'll show the images here in a second to give you an example of what I mean.  So for me, after click-selecting my wanted axis, the tool selection only spans as far as the second next edge, where as for the instructor it spans around the entire wall - in this case I'm trying to mark a selection to extrude skirting.

The instructor using the tool:
[image]

How the tool behaves for me:
[image]

You can see that when creating the two horizontal edges (for the window) using this tool I had the same problem where the selection would only go as far as the second edge intersection it met.
[image]

Comment: There is error somewhere in geometry on the third screenshot which probably leads to result in the second screenshot - either an Ngon (it can visually look the same as quad but have a vertex somewhere) or an internal face in the mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a step by step instruction that shows you how to get the same result as the instructor did; hope it helps:

[image: BasicShape]

Start with the same basic wall shape

[image: AddLoopCuts]

Now you add the two loop cuts (Ctrl + R) for the top and bottom of the window sill.   By using the scroll wheel you can change the number of cuts you want to make, and then you can arrange them where you want.

[image: SideLoopCuts]

Now add cuts for the sides of the window.

[image: Finished]

All you have to do now is grab the faces where the window is gonna be and delete them.  To fill up the resulting gap, grab the outer edges of the window on both sides using edge select, hit ctrl+E, and select "Bridge Edge Loops".  And there is your window!  You should have no problems adding any loop cuts.

Comment: Thanks for that!  I' still having this realy strange issue  when I got to create my first loop cuts by selecting the tool and mousing over the area, I' only ever getting the option to create the vertical ones first.

Comment: weird... could you post a picture of the object right before you try to add any loop cuts?  Post it in vertex select.

Comment: Like this? https://imgur.com/TtOe9kS

Comment: Yeah.  What I was looking for was to see if one of your faces had more than four vertices.  That could cause a problem during loop cutting.  Why don't you look it over and make sure?

Comment: You may not know this;  When adding a horizontal loop cut, you have to mouse near a vertical loop on this mesh.  Try that.

Comment: It doesn't appear that I have more than 4 vertices on any face.  When I create the vertical loop cuts first and then try horizontal ones,, the same thing happens where it only spans so far.  Maybe this was a bad idea for a first tutorial. https://imgur.com/6jS9tsf

Comment: I don't think so.  Could you drag me through the exact process you went through in order to make this shape?  I know it's tedious, but I think it'll help me figure it out.

Comment: Well, I used the startup cube for the floor by just using the scale tool.  I then duplicated the floor and again using the scale tool turned that into the wall (the wall with the future windows).  I used the loop cut and slide tool to create the wall on the right by creating a new edge, then selecting that face and using extrude.  That's everything I did up until I started creating the window.

Comment: Do you have any faces INSIDE the wall?  If so, delete them.  That should stop the problem.

Comment: That was it.  It took a lot of looking around in wireframe mode to figure out what was going on but there was a face from where I extruded the end on one wall to create the other.  Thanks a lot ^^

Comment: Great!  Glad you found the problem!  Have fun!  Would you like me to change my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new and just now marked it answered.  I think you should leave it as is, it might help people a lot more if they can see how we (read: you) figured it out.  Also, I relaised that I had the "Limit selection to visible" toggled on and it was hiding the face from me in wireframe mode until I unchecked it.  Again, thanks!

Comment: No problem.  By the way, you're not the only new one; I just joined about 3 days ago! :D  Thanks for the points.  Now I can finally comment on other people's questions! :D

Answer (score 1):

The face at the right of the window is a NGon (a polygon with more than 4 vertices). NGons prevent Loop Cut to find his "way" in your topology, so LoopCut just stops when he found a NGon.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I kinda get that - but how did the instructor manage to do it then?  As you can see in the image, after I created the 2 vertical edges for the window the Loop Cut would not go past the second edge.  You can see that the instructor has 2 more faces on that wall.

Comment: I added a third image to describe what I meant.